# How can I convert this date only string into a proper date for use with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, this string works perfectly for automation in selenium:

> dateofincident = self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

It fills out a required date field. However, I need to use a different date pulled from a Google sheet. So, if I print nextdate, my output is: 5/5/2020

Trying to pass nextdate (data from google sheets) as a string doesn't work. It won't fill out the date field.

How can I convert "5/5/2020" into the same type of data produced by self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')?

Comment: `strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`?

Comment: This did not work :/